# How to use ng-change in typescript1

Tags: typescript

Please suggest me how to use ng-change in typescript1. Here I have some code

```
   <input type="text" ng-change="epc.fileChangeEvent()" />
```

typescript

```
fileChangeEvent():void {
         alert('file change');
        }
```

This is out of construction. Here I'm using kendo

Comment: Please include the framework you're using. It looks like you're using AngularJS, and possibly Kendo, but those tags are missing from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ng from ng-change

```
 <input type="text" (change)="fileChangeEvent()" >
```

in your component:

```
fileChangeEvent():void {
    alert('file change');
 };
```

Comment: sorry bro i need ng-change

Comment: just change it to (change)

Comment: what is the error?? and why you writing epc.fileChangeEvent ?

Comment: ITS NOT THROUGHING ANY Error here im using kendo popup

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange                    <input type="text" ng-change="fileChangeEvent()" />

Comment: Yeah, (change)= works. Thanks Sainu! I don't know why this isn't apparently documented anywhere other than this SO answer; but this is my experience of using Angular. Nobody knows how it works because the designers won't leave the syntax alone for 2 minutes.

Comment: @Hussain if you are using ngModel you can use ngModelChange. (I've just discovered this). But I note you aren't in the example.